# HTML5 Audio Tag Volume control is Not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm using a HTML5 audio tag to play the audio from the internet.

It's perfectly working on PC browsers and Android browsers.

IN IOS mobile browsers Volume control is not working,

Is there a workaround to correct this?

```html
<audio #audioplayer [src]="audioUrl"></audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers supports a little different sets of media formats. It's possible, that iOS's browser don't support your audio format.

Answer (score 0):

To add volume change support to iOS and not rewrite your entire app from html5 audio to web audio for that, you can combine these audio solutions via createMediaElementSource.

Please see more details at Mozilla website https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource